# Создать если не существует иначе обновить

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица table (id, goods, country, price).
Добавляю в неё данные с проверкой существования goods, если поле существует - обновляю определённые поля.

```
INSERT INTO $bd (goods, country, price)
VALUES ('$v1', '$v2', '$v3')
on duplicate key update bid = values(country), ask = values(price)
```

Позже решил добавить в базу товары из других стран, решил сделать так `table (id, goods, country, price, country2, price2)` получилась какая-то хренотня, потом разделил таблицу на 3
`goods(id, name, desctription), country(idCountry, country)` и `prices(idPrices, price)` связал их между собой по ключам id, idCountry и idPrices
и вот теперь вопрос, как модифицировать мой запрос к базе что бы вставить данные в 3 таблице, либо обновить country и price, если name существует?

Answer (score 0):

Для наглядности приложите схему БД, а так:

```
INSERT INTO $bd (goods, country, price)
VALUES ('$v1', '$v2', '$v3')
on duplicate <key> update bid = values(country), ask = values(price)
```

key - это либо первичный ключ, либо уникальный индекс.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: а какую схему? я же описал базы goods(id, name, desctription), country(idCountry, country) и prices(idPrices, price) А что изменилось, вы мне тот же запрос отправили?

Comment: В документации написано on duplicate key работает только если у вас появляются дублирующие значения в первичном ключе или уникальном индексе. В данном случаи у вас должен быть либо составной первичный ключ или уникальный индекс

Comment: Да, name имеет уникальный индекс, вопрос в том как обновлять поля в других 2 таблицах, если в name попал дубль? А так же если значения в name не существует, то добавить, новую строку в таблицу goods и 2 другие country и prices

Comment: INSERT делает вставку только в одну таблицу и одним запросом не получится. В таком варианте можно проверку на уникальность делать на стороне сервера или написать хранимую процедуру, которая сделает вставку или обновление таблиц в зависимости  от уникальности поля `name`